# Trying to understand what is meant by "hash context"

Tags: hash

Could someone explain what is meant by 'context' here?

> As the data is hashed, it is given independently to each hash
> context.  Since the contexts have been initialized differently, they
> will each produce different hash output.**  Once the passphrase is
> hashed, the output data from the multiple hashes is concatenated,
> first hash leftmost, to produce the key data, with any excess octets
> on the right discarded.

source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-3.7.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it in the earlier part of the same document you link:

> 3.7.1.1. Simple S2K
>
> This directly hashes the string to produce the key data.  See below
>      for how this hashing is done.

```
   Octet 0:        0x00
   Octet 1:        hash algorithm
```

> Simple S2K hashes the passphrase to produce the session key.  The
>      manner in which this is done depends on the size of the session key
>      (which will depend on the cipher used) and the size of the hash
>      algorithm's output.  If the hash size is greater than the session key
>      size, the high-order (leftmost) octets of the hash are used as the
>      key.

So say you're after a session key of 128 bits, but the hash algorithm outputs 256 bit values, you'll simply rip off the 128 high-order bits and use those as the session key.

> If the hash size is less than the key size, multiple instances of the
>      hash context are created -- enough to produce the required key data.
>      These instances are preloaded with 0, 1, 2, ... octets of zeros (that
>      is to say, the first instance has no preloading, the second gets
>      preloaded with 1 octet of zero, the third is preloaded with two
>      octets of zeros, and so forth).

Say we're after a session key of 512 bits and the hash algorithm outputs 128 bit values, we create 4 hash contexts as 4 hash outputs together will provide the needed 512 bits.  We're basically going to use the same hash algorithm to generate four values, but to make sure the four values are adding some value we initialise/seed them differently.  In Object Oriented programming, if you imagine the hash algorithm being embodied in a class such that you could do something like this pseudo-code...

```
Hash my_hash(seed);
for (word in data)
    my_hash.feed(word);
use my_hash.output();
```

...then you could consider each `Hash` object to be a *context*, and for a session key wider than the hash output width you're just doing something like this:

```
Hash my_hashes[4] = { seed1, seed2, seed3, seed4 };
for (word in data)
    for (my_hash in my_hashes)
         my_hash.feed(word);
512_bit_hash = my_hash[0] + my_hash[1] + my_hash[2] + my_hash[3];
```